# FTP server for content distribution

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I need to set up an FTP server for distributing various versions of a software package to a number of user accounts.

To avoid copying the files to each user's ftp home folder, I would like to set up a 'shared file environment' with symlinks using a structure much like this :

```
/
...
+-- srv
    +-- ftp
        +-- data
            +-- V1
                +-- Latest            -> /srv/ftp/data/V1/V1.3
                +-- V1.1
                +-- V1.2
                +-- V1.3
            +-- V2
                +-- Latest            -> /srv/ftp/data/V2/V2.2
                +-- V2.1
                +-- V2.2
            +-- V3
                +-- Latest            -> /srv/ftp/data/V3/V3.1
                +-- V3.1
        +-- users
            +-- user1
                +-- V3                -> /srv/ftp/data/V3/Latest
            +-- user2
                +-- V2                -> /srv/ftp/data/V2/Latest
            +-- user3
```

Each version is a folder with several files and subfolders.

I'm using a linux box (CentOS 7) with vsftpd; my problem comes when I try to limit user access to his home folder; the server will not allow following the link outside the user's folder.

For instance, I would like user1 to see only the V3 folder and its content (with sub-folders)

So the questions is : is this the right approach ? if yes, how to get it to work, if not, what would be the  recommended approach for something like this ?

Comment: Why would you want ftp over e.g. http or sftp?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but that's not the point of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general consideration: stop using the legacy FTP protocol for content distribution.

---

As an alternative to using symbolic links you can use a ["bind" mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198590/48232) to replicate  part of your file system elsewhere, for example in a users personal directory hierarchy.
Bind mounts shouldn't interfere with chroot confinement strategies.

The following syntax is equivalent:

```
mount --bind /srv/ftp/data/V3/Latest /srv/ftp/users/user1/V3
mount -o bind srv/ftp/data/V2/Latest /srv/ftp//users/user2/V2
```

Create the associated entries in `/etc/fstab` to make that persistent across reboots.

Comment: thank you. it's exactly what I needed